# Getting error with sqldatareader

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Im trying to get the column lengths of all my columns. the query works in sql management studio but when i run it in my code in VS i get an exception message saying  "specified cast in invalid" my code is:

```
  public void getLength()
   {
    string connectionString = "Data Source=." + "\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial     Catalog=" + drlDatabases.SelectedItem.ToString() + ";User    Id=test2;Password=test2;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string selectSql = "SELECT max_length FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id =   OBJECT_ID('" + drlTables.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
    SqlDataReader r = null;

    try

    {
        con.Open();
        r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int val = 0;
        while (r.Read())
        {
            colLength[val] = r.GetInt32(val);
        }


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblex.Text = ex.Message;
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is thrown, because SQL server is not returning an integer (in fact, it is unsure which datatype is returned when using aggregate functions).
Try something more robust, like this
colLength

> colLength[val] = Convert.ToInt32(r["max_length"])

Comment: thanks, but now i get object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Sorry, it should be colLength[val] = Convert.ToInt32(r["max_length"])

Comment: The correct answer is to cast it to the correct type with `SqlDataReader.GetInt16`. It's [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) that `max_length` from sys.columns is `smallint` which counterpart in .NET is `Int16`(`short`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetInt16` instead of `GetInt32`:

```
colLength[val] = r.GetInt16(val);
```

because the [type of this column is `smallint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) and the .NET counterpart is `Int16`.

[`SqlDataReader.GetInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx) throws this exception if the cast is not valid.

Comment: hie, thanks tried it but now getting this: Object reference not set to an instance of an objec

Comment: @focused: so your original issue is fixed now. Where do you get the NRE? Maybe `colLength` is `null` but you haven't shown where it is declared or initialized.

Comment: i declared it as a global array like: int[] colLength=null;